# Execute command parsed from a string containing arguments with spaces

Tags: bash

I would like to execute a command which is given by a variable (Variable `cmd` in this example):

```
cmd="echo 'First argument'"
$cmd
```

Expected result would be:

```
First argument
```

BUT ... actual result is:

```
'First argument'
```

What? I don't understand why I can see single quotes in the output. After all, if the command (=content of variable $cmd) would be issued directly, then no quotes leak into the output, it behaves as desired:

```
$ echo 'First argument'
First argument
```

To illustrate what I am trying to achieve in real life: in my deploy script there is a code block like this (strongly simplified, but you get the point):

```
#!/bin/bash
function execute {
    cmd=$1
    echo "Executing $cmd ..."

    # execute the command:
    $cmd
}    

VERSION=1.0.2
execute "git tag -a 'release-$VERSION'"
```

Now, Git would create a tag which contains single quotes:

```
git tag
'1.0.2'
```

which is not what I want ...

What to do?

(Bash version: GNU bash 3.1.0)

(I found a very similar issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983048/passing-a-string-with-spaces-as-a-function-argument-in-bash), but the answer would not apply to my problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmd="echo 'First argument'"
$cmd
```

What happens there is word splitting and the actual resulting command is:

```
echo "'First" "argument'"
```

Double-parsing with the single quotes inside would never happen.

Also, it's better to use arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

function execute {
    cmd=("$@")  ## $@ is already similar to an array and storing it to another is just optional.
    echo "Executing ${cmd[*]} ..."

    # execute the command:
    "${cmd[@]}"
}    

VERSION=1.0.2
execute git tag -a "release-$VERSION"
```

For `eval` is a difficult choice in that kind of situation. You may not only get unexpected parsing results, but also unexpectedly run dangerous commands.

Comment: Marvellous! Great explanation and very clean code - I adopted your solution, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
cmd="echo 'First arg'"
eval $cmd
First arg
```

Comment: Yep. Works, thanks. However, I prefer to avoid eval, that's why I chose konsolebox' solution.