# How can Ruby OptionParser take care of parameter with spaces?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to define the options for my Ruby script which sending messages from User A to User B for testing purpose. However I couldn't get it work when some of the option have spaces in the value. For example:

```
    OptionParser.new do |opts|
      opts.on("-p", "--params a=A,b=B,c=C", Array, "Parameters to compose the message") do |params|
        options.params = params.map { |p| p.split("=") }
      end
    end
```

But when I try to specify thing like `-p SENDER=foo,RECIPIENT=bar,BODY=foo bar` it just gave me back `["SENDER" => "foo", "RECIPIENT" => "bar", "BODY" => "foo"]`.

I have also tried `-p SENDER=foo,RECIPIENT=bar,BODY='foo bar'` but no luck with it either.

Does OptionParser support this scenario?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single or double quotes to surround the parameter:

```
-p 'SENDER=foo,RECIPIENT=bar,BODY=foo bar'
```

For example:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on('-p', '--params OPTS', Array) { |o| options[:p] = o }
end.parse!

require 'pp'
pp options # =>
```

Running that at the command-line using:

```
ruby test.rb --params 'SENDER=foo,RECIPIENT=bar,BODY=foo bar'
```

Outputs:

```
{:p=>["SENDER=foo", "RECIPIENT=bar", "BODY=foo bar"]}
```

This isn't an OptionParser issue, it's how the command-line works when parsing the options and passing them to the script. OptionParse only gets involved once it sees the argument `'SENDER=foo,RECIPIENT=bar,BODY=foo bar'` and splits it on the commas into an array and passes that to the `opt.on` block:

```
'SENDER=foo,RECIPIENT=bar,BODY=foo bar'.split(',')
# => ["SENDER=foo", "RECIPIENT=bar", "BODY=foo bar"]
```

---

It looks like you're trying to split the incoming data into an array of arrays because of:

```
options.params = params.map { |p| p.split("=") }
```

I'd recommend considering converting it into a hash instead:

```
opt.on('-p', '--params OPTS', Array) { |o| options[:p] = Hash[o.map{ |s| s.split('=') }] }
```

Which results in:

```
{:p=>{"SENDER"=>"foo", "RECIPIENT"=>"bar", "BODY"=>"foo bar"}}
```

And makes it easy to get at specific entries passed in:

```
pp options[:p]['BODY'] # => "foo bar"
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I just tested and OptionParser works fine. The problem actually is introduced by the shell script that on top of it. The script is simply doing `ruby test.rb $*`. Is there a way I can fix the shell script? Or it is just the behavior of shell?

Comment: I got the shell script works by following this stackoverflow question. Thank you very much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983048/passing-a-string-with-spaces-as-a-function-argument-in-bash