# How to send a string with spaces from Python to Bash sub-process as a single value?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I'm trying to send a variable from a python script to a bash script. I'm using `popen` like as shown below:

```
subprocess.Popen(["bash", "-c", ". mainGui_functions.sh %d %s" % (commandNum.get(), entryVal)])
```

However, `entryVal` can sometimes contain one or more white space characters. In that case I divide the string into multiple arguments ($2,$3..)

How can i get it in one argument?

Comment: Try to add full path to mainGui_functions.sh.

Comment: have you tried adding quotes around entryVal...something like this `"%d \"%s\""`

Comment: Perhaps this might help, coming from the bash script end of things https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983048/passing-a-string-with-spaces-as-a-function-argument-in-bash

Comment: Also, consider using `str.format` instead of interpolating with the `%` character, for a more Pythonic style.

Comment: Starting a Bash instance so you can source a file and then immediately exit is just weird. Unless this is a simplified version of something which is more complex in reality, you simply want `Popen(['bash', 'mainGui_functions', str(commandNum.get()), entryVal])` (the `'bash'` can be omitted, too, if the script has execute permission and a proper shebang line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution #1: You do it the exact same way you'd do it if you were typing the input on the commandline; put it in quotes:

```
subprocess.Popen(["bash", "-c", ". mainGui_functions.sh {} '{}'".format(commandNum.get(), entryVal)])
```

Simple solution #2: If `mainGui_functions.sh` is already executable, then you can just omit the `bash` part and pas args to it directly. In this case, `subprocess` takes care of making sure an entry with whitespace winds up as a single arg for you:

```
subprocess.Popen(["mainGui_functions.sh", str(commandNum.get()), entryVal])
```

Comment: Added missing quotes around `"mainGui_functions.sh"`, from `"mainGui_functions.sh` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around it in your bash command line – e.g.,

```
subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', '. mainGui_functions.sh %d "%s"' % (commandNum.get(), entryVal)])
```