# Bash script string with spaces arguments is not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Bash arguments with space not working, even I am using quotes in aruments

```
update_config_entry() {
  echo
  echo -e "${RED}CONFIG-UPDATE${NC} Ensure $1 is updated in $2"

  if grep -Fx $1 $2; then
    echo "$1 already exist in file $2"
  else
    echo $1 >> $2
  fi

  policystatus=$?

  if [[ "$policystatus" -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo -e "${GREEN}Remediated:${NC} Ensure $1 is updated in $2"
  else
    echo -e "${RED}UnableToRemediate:${NC} Ensure $1 is updated in $2"
fi

}

update_config_entry "install usb-storage /bin/true" /etc/modprobe.d/CIS.conf
```

Error:

```
grep: usb-storage: No such file or directory
grep: /bin/true": No such file or directory
```

"install usb-storage /bin/true" should go single argument but it is passing install usb-storage /bin/true as separate arument. what I am doing wrong,

other places recomended  enclose with quotes and I am already doing
it

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983048/passing-a-string-with-spaces-as-a-function-argument-in-bash)

Bash script
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Run your script through https://shellcheck.net

Comment: It **is** passed to your string as a single argument. You can verify it if you do something like `echo ">>>$1<<<" at the start of your function `update_config_entry `.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to quote the argument to `grep`. It should be

```
grep -Fx "$1" "$2"
```

otherwise grep receives

```
grep -Fx install usb-storage /bin/true /etc/modprobe.d/CIS.conf
```

which means that it is asked to search the file *usb-storage*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that your double quotes are not sufficient. I tried the following:

```
update_config_entry """install usb-storage /bin/true""" /etc/modprobe.d/CIS.conf
```

It looked quite well.

Comment: The extra double-quotes don't do anything at all (each extra pair actually cancel each other out).

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting fix:

```
update_config_entry() {
  echo
  echo -e "${RED}CONFIG-UPDATE${NC} Ensure $1 is updated in $2"

  if [[ $(grep -Fxc "$1" "$2") -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "$1 already exist in file $2"
  else
    echo "$1" >> "$2"
  fi

  policystatus=$?

  if [[ "$policystatus" -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo -e "${GREEN}Remediated:${NC} Ensure $1 is updated in $2"
  else
    echo -e "${RED}UnableToRemediate:${NC} Ensure $1 is updated in $2"
fi

}

update_config_entry "install usb-storage /bin/true" /etc/modprobe.d/CIS.conf
```