Add prefix to git commit message using LazyGit custom command
I want to add my ticket name-number automatically to my commits. The ticket value is included as prefix in my branch eg: TEST-12345-my-branch-name.
This is the command I want to fix:
git commit -m ''$(git branch --contains | grep '*' | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F'-' '{print $1"-"$2}' | awk '{print $1 ":{{.Form.Message}}"}')''

And this is the whole custom command in LazyGit configuration file:
customCommands:
  - key: "<c-c>"
    context: "files"
    prompts:
      - type: "input"
        title: "Add Commit Message"
        key: "Message"

    command: git commit -m ''$(git branch --contains | grep '*' | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F'-' '{print $1"-"$2}' | awk '{print $1 ":{{.Form.Message}}"}')''
    subprocess: true

    description: "Custom commit message"


I am able to make it work when the message has no spaces in it(eg. my-commit-message -> TEST-12345-my-commit-message). But, if I try to add my commit message message, it gives me the next error:
error: pathspec 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'message' did not match any file(s) known to git

I expect to have a commit message like TEST-12345 my commit message.
I think the problem is the last pipe's awk awk '{print $1 ":{{.Form.Message}}"}'. Could you please help me to fix it? I do not know how to make progress. Thank you.

hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/1983070/1978365

What does '' do? You realize that's not a double quote but two single quotes, right? Is it a special 'lazygit' syntax?

I do not think it is a 'lazygit' syntax. It was the way prettier edit it so I kept using it. I think I need it to do not close " when it is inside the command, right?

'' is a null string. Your code is semantically identical with or without it. If you're using an editor that suggests using '' for anything then, seriously, get a new editor. You can nest double quotes and/or use single quotes inside $(...), e.g. whatever "$(echo "foo" 'bar')".

@EdMorton yes, I am migrating to nvim now. I still confused why the nested " did not mess the code, that is why I thought I needed the double single quotes. Anyway, thanks all for the lesson.

@programandoconro nested " don't mess with the code because that's just the way "$(...)" is designed to function. That's one of the reasons why $(...) is better than <backtick>...<backtick>.

@EdMorton noted! Thanks. I will try to improve my awk from now on.

You're welcome. Any time you find yourself doing sed-or-grep-or-awk | sed-or-grep-or-awk that that is an antipattern that could be implemented with a single call to awk (or sometimes sed) instead.

The duplicated single quotes do absolutely nothing here. Instead, you want to embed the entire command substitution inside double quotes.
I have refactored it into a single Awk process for efficiency. I'm displaying it on multiple lines for legibility.
git commit -m "$(git branch --contains |
    awk -v m="{{.Form.Message}}" '
      /\*/{split($2, n, /-/);
        print (n[1] "-" n[2] ":" m)}')"

See also When to wrap quotes around a shell variable? and perhaps useless use of grep | awk

I get awk: syntax error at source line 1  context is  /\*/{split($2, n, /-/); print (n[1] "-" >>>  n[2]} <<< awk: illegal statement at source line 1 awk: illegal statement at source line 1  extra }  missing )

I just replaced the duplicated single quotes for double quotes in my previous attempt as you said and now it works. Thank you so much. Could you please edit you answer? Please fix or remove the refactor so I can accept this answer. Thanks again!

Sorry about that; added the missing closing parenthesis.

git commit -m "$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD) - {{.Form.Message}}"

@LéaGris But that fails to parse out the ticket number from the start of the branch name; though git commit -m "$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD | cut -d- -f1-2) - {{.Form.Message}" would work for that.
